# counting (large number of) strings within (very large) text

Tags: python, lucene, full-text-search, nltk

I've seen a couple variations of the "efficiently search for strings within file(s)" question on Stackoverflow but not quite like my situation.

- I've got one text file which contains a relatively large number (>300K) of strings.    The vast majority of these strings are multiple words (for ex., "Plessy v. Ferguson", "John Smith", etc.).
- From there, I need to search through a very large set of text files (a set of legal docs totaling >10GB) and tally the instances of those strings.

Because of the number of search strings, the strings having multiple words, and the size of the search target, a lot of the "standard" solutions seem fall to the wayside.

Some things simplify the problem a little -

- I don't need sophisticated tokenizing / stemming / etc.   (e.g. the only instances I care about are "Plessy v. Ferguson", don't need to worry about "Plessy", "Plessy et. al." etc.)
- there will be some duplicates (for ex., multiple people named "John Smith"), however, this isn't a very statistically significant issue for this dataset so... if multiple John Smith's get conflated into a single tally, that's ok for now.
- I only need to count these specific instances;  I don't need to return search results
- 10 instances in 1 file count the same as 1 instance in each of 10 files

Any suggestions for quick / dirty ways to solve this problem?

I've investigated NLTK, Lucene & others but they appear to be overkill for the problem I'm trying to solve.   Should I suck it up and import everything into a DB?  bruteforce grep it 300k times?   ;)

My preferred dev tool is Python.

---

The docs to be searched are primarily legal docs like this - http://www.lawnix.com/cases/plessy-ferguson.html

The intended results are tallys for how often the case is referenced across those docs - 
"Plessey v. Ferguson:  15"

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what the input is and what you would like to do with it? Examples like before/after are always nice! Really help to provide a good answer...

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to solve this is to build a trie with your queries (simply a prefix tree, list of nodes with a single character inside), and when you search through your 10gb file you go through your tree recursively as the text matches.

This way you prune *a lot* of options really early on in your search for each character position in the big file, while still searching your whole solution space.

Time performance will be very good (as good as a lot of other, more complicated solutions) and you'll only need enough space to store the tree (a lot less than the whole array of strings) and a small buffer into the large file. Definitely a lot better than grepping a db 300k times...

Comment: Thanks blindy!    Any strategy suggestions for populating && searching the tree when i'm dealing with a potentially multi-word string ("John Smith")?   It's relatively straightforward to add "John Smith" to the trie but then, when I'm searching through the 10gb, it seems I might have to test every word multiple times.     For ex., in the fragment "give to John Smith", i'd have to search the trie for "give to", "to John", and "John Smith"

Comment: Yes but for each character in the file to search, you're already pruning your data exponentially. Like if your "cursor" is on "to John", you already pruned every starting letter except `t` from the tree, so "John Smith" will never be matched. This makes matching O(m) for a given character, so O(nm) total (basically quadratic but the maximum length of a search string is insignificant compared to the full document).

Comment: As to multi-word strings, I'd add them as they are and run my normal search algorithm on them. The only post-processing step I'd do is if my query string has a space, I "eat" all spaces in my input if i get there. Still linear search though.

Answer (score 0):

You have several constraints you must deal with, which makes this a complex problem.

1. Hard drive IO
2. Memory space
3. Processing time

I would suggest writing a multithreaded/multiprocess python app. The libraries to subprocess are painless. Have each process read in a file, and the parse tree as suggested by Blindy. When it finishes, it returns the results to the parent, which writes them to a file.

This will use up as many resources as you can throw at it, while allowing for expansion. If you stick it on a beowulf cluster, it will transparently share the processes across your cpus for you.

The only sticking point is the hard drive IO. Break it into chunks on different hard drives, and as each process finishes, start a new one and load a file. If you're on linux, all of the files can coexist in the same filesystem namespace, and your program won't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly brute-force solution won't work.

Time one grep through your documents and extrapolate the time it takes for 300k greps (and possibly try parallelizing it if you have many machines available), is it feasible?  My guess is that 300k searches won't be feasible.  E.g., greping one search through ~50 Mb of files took me about ~5s, so for 10 Gb, you'd expect ~1000s, and then repeating 300k times means you'd be done in about 10 years with one computer.  You can parallelize to get some improvements (limited by disk io on one computer), but still will be quite limited.  I assume you want the task to be finished in hours rather than months, so this isn't likely a solution.

So you are going to need to index the documents somehow.  Lucene (say through pythonsolr) or Xapian should be suitable for your purpose.  Index the documents, then search the indexed documents.

Answer (score 0):

You should use group pattern matching algorithms which use dynamic algorithms to reuse evaluation. I.e. Aho–Corasick . Implementations

- http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/wiki/RegexpOptimization
- http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/dict/ExactDictionaryChunker.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this idea is extremely stupid or not, please let me know...

Divide the files to be searched into reasonably sized numbers 10/100/1000... and for each "chunk" use an indexing SW available for SW. Here I'm thinking about [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) [gnu global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) or perhaps the `ptx` utility or using a technique described in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869997/vim-how-to-index-a-plain-text-file).

Using this technique, you "only" need to search through the index files for the target strings.