# Vim: How to number paragraphs automatically and how to refer to this numbering?

Tags: vim

Let us say I have the following three paragraphs of text (separated
from each other by empty lines—number 3 and 7, here):

```
This is my first paragraph line 1
This is my first paragraph line 2

This is my second paragraph line 4
This is my second paragraph line 5
This is my second paragraph line 6

This is my third paragraph line 8
This is my third paragraph line 9
```

**Question 1:** How can I number these paragraphs automatically,
to obtain this result:

```
1   This is my first paragraph line 1
    This is my first paragraph line 2

2   This is my second paragraph line 4
    This is my second paragraph line 5
    This is my second paragraph line 6

3   This is my third paragraph line 8
    This is my third paragraph line 9
```

(I succeeded to do this, but only via a clumsy macro.)

**Question 2:** Is it possible to refer to these paragraphs? For
instance, is it possible to index a text file as answered (by Prince
Goulash and Herbert Sitz) in [the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869997/vim-how-to-index-a-plain-text-file), but this time
with the paragraph numbers and not the line numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think a macro is a bad idea, just create a variable `i` and increment it after inserting with `<c-r>=i`. However, if you do this often, then I agree that a better solution is needed. VimScript.

Comment: Your text, in Vim, might not actually be the best place to do that. Instead you could just write some kind of markup, with placeholder variables or auto-incrementing markup, and run the text through that. Something reStructuredText, or Markdown, roff, or TeX are commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question One**

Here is a function to enumerate paragraphs. Simply do `:call EnumeratePara()` anywhere in your file. The variable `indent` can be adjusted as you wish. Let me know if anything needs correcting or explaining.

```
function! EnumeratePara()
    let indent = 5
    let lnum = 1
    let para = 1
    let next_is_new_para = 1
    while lnum <= line("$")
        let this = getline(lnum)
        if this =~ "^ *$"
            let next_is_new_para=1
        elseif next_is_new_para == 1 && this !~ "^ *$"
            call cursor(lnum, 1)
            sil exe "normal i" . para . repeat(" ", indent-len(para))
            let para+=1
            let next_is_new_para = 0
        else
            call cursor(lnum, 1)
            sil exe "normal i" . repeat(" ", indent)
        endif
        let lnum += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

**Question Two**

This isn't a very elegant approach, but it seems to work. First of all, here's a function that maps each line in the file to a paragraph number:

```
function! MapLinesToParagraphs()
    let lnum = 1
    let para_lines = []
    let next_is_new_para = 1
    let current_para = 0
    while lnum <= line("$")
        let this = getline(lnum)
        if this =~ "^ *$"
            let next_is_new_para = 1
        elseif next_is_new_para == 1
            let current_para += 1
            let next_is_new_para = 0
        endif
        call add(para_lines, current_para)
        let lnum += 1
    endwhile
    return para_lines
endfunction
```

So that `para_lines[i]` will give the paragraph of line `i`.

Now we can use the existing `IndexByWord()` function, and use `MapLinesToParagraph()` to convert the line numbers into paragraph numbers before we return them:

```
function! IndexByParagraph(wordlist)
    let temp_dict = {}
    let para_lines = MapLinesToParagraphs()
    for word in a:wordlist
        redir => result
        sil! exe ':g/' . word . '/#'
        redir END
        let tmp_list = split(strtrans(result), "\\^\@ *")
        let res_list = []
        call map(tmp_list, 'add(res_list, str2nr(matchstr(v:val, "^[0-9]*")))')
        call map(res_list, 'para_lines[v:val]')
        let temp_dict[word] = res_list
    endfor
    let result_list = []
    for key in sort(keys(temp_dict))
        call add(result_list, key . ' : ' . string(temp_dict[key])[1:-2])
    endfor
    return join(result_list, "\n")
endfunction
```

I have not tested these functions very thoroughly, but they seem to work okay, at least in your example text. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: :this is exactly what I was looking for, and it works nice (NB : I noticed I had a index problem with the last paragraph only, so I created a "fake" last paragraph, called, of course, THE END, which solved that tiny glitch). Thank you very much.

Comment: that "tiny glitch" isn't even a glitch at all : the only constraint is to have an empty line (I should have thought of that...) after the last paragraph in order to close it, of course. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do the ref numbers, with a pair of functions:

```
function! MakeRefMarkers()
     " Remove spaces from empty lines:
     %s/^ \+$//
     " Mark all spots for ref number:
     %s/^\_$\_.\zs\(\s\|\S\)/_parref_/
     " Initialize ref val:
     let s:i = 0
     " Replace with ref nums:
     %s/^_parref_/\=GetRef()/
endfunction

function! GetRef()
     let s:i += 1
     return s:i . '.  '
endfunction
```

Then just do it by calling `MakeRefMarkers()`.  It doesn't remove existing ref numbers if they're there, that would require another step. And it doesn't catch first paragraph if it's first line in file (i.e, without preceding blank line). But it does handle situations where there's more than one blank line between paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I shall nevertheless keep Prince Goulash's, which suits my needs more adequately. Thanks again (and once more for IndexByWord !)

Answer (score 1):

Both problems could be solved much easier than it is suggested
by the other two answers.

**1.** In order to solve the first problem of numbering paragraphs,
the following two steps are ample.

Indent the paragraphs (using tabs, here):

```
    :v/^\s*$/s/^/\t/
```

Insert paragraph numbering (see also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942360/gvim-find-replace-with-counter/5944828#5944828) to
[the question on substitution with counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942360/gvim-find-replace-with-counter)):

```
    :let n=[0] | %s/^\s*\n\zs\ze\s*\S\|\%1l/\=map(n,'v:val+1')
```

**2.** The second problem of creating index requires some scripting in
order to be solved by Vim means only. Below is the listing of a small
function, `WordParIndex()` that is supposed to be run after paragraphs
are numbered according to the first problem's description.

```
function! WordParIndex()
    let [p, fq] = [0, {}]
    let [i, n] = [1, line('$')]
    while i <= n
        let l = getline(i)
        if l !~ '^\s*$'
            let [p; ws] = ([p] + split(l, '\s\+'))[l=~'^\S':]
            for w in ws
                let t = get(fq, w, [p])
                let fq[w] = t[-1] != p ? t + [p] : t
            endfor
        endif
        let i += 1
    endwhile
    return fq
endfunction
```

The return value of the `WordParIndex()` function is the target index
dictionary. To append its text representation at the end of a buffer,
run

```
:call map(WordParIndex(), 'append(line("$"),v:key.": ".join(v:val,","))')
```

Comment: @ib : Thank you for your answer. I shall nevertheless keep Prince Goulash's, which, in my case, fits exactly as I wish. Thanks again. ThG

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be macro based:

1. Yank the number "0" somehow and move to the start of the first paragraph.
2. Record a macro to

   1. Indent the paragraph with `>}`
   2. Paste the stored number at the correct position `p`
   3. Increment the number by one with `<ctrl>-a`
   4. Yank the pasted number with `yiw`
   5. Move to the next paragraph with `}l` or `/^\S`
3. Execute the macro as many times as needed to reach the end of the document.

---

The method of pasting a number, incrementing it, and then reyanking it inside a macro is quite a useful technique that comes in handy whenever you need to number things. And it's simple enough to just do it in a throw-away fashion. I mainly use it for carpet logging, but it has other uses as your question demonstrates.