# How to paste the results of a :g/foo/p search at the end of the file ?

Tags: vim

1) I search foo in a file with the global command :g :

```
:g/foo/p
```

and I want to paste the results at the end of the file. How must I proceed ?

2) Same question (or is it ?) with the results of an echo statement :

```
:echo IndexByWord(['word1', 'word2', 'word3', etc])
```

(about this function, see : [Vim : how to index a plain text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869997/vim-how-to-index-a-plain-text-file))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) `:call append('$', split(IndexByWord(['foo', 'bar']), '\n'))`

`:h append(`

```
append({lnum}, {expr})                  *append()*
        When {expr} is a |List|: Append each item of the |List| as a
        text line below line {lnum} in the current buffer.
```

`:h split(`

```
split({expr} [, {pattern} [, {keepempty}]])         *split()*
        Make a |List| out of {expr}.
```

Using `'$'` as lnum is equal to the last line in the buffer.

You need to use split() because the function you referred to, IndexByWord(), returns a string. It looks to me that you might want to change IndexByWord() to return a list.

If you change this line in IndexByWord():

`return join(result_list, "\n")`

into

`return result_list`

Appending is a bit simpler then:

`:call append('$', IndexByWord(['foo', 'bar']))`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about (2), but for (1), change it to `:g/foo/t$`.  This will copy (`t`) the line to the last addressable line (`$`).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Btw, I tried it for question #2 (:echo IndexByWord(['foo']) | t$), but of course failed miserably.

Answer (score 4):

You can redirect the messages to a register

```
:redi @"
:g/foo/p
:redi END
:$pu
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for question #1, but I could not figure how to make it work for question #2. Thanks again.

Comment: @ThG: just replace `:g/foo/p` with `:echo IndexByWord(['word1', 'word2', 'word3', etc])` for #2. For more information about redirection see `:h :redi`

Comment: Thanks, however I just tried this, and it just creates a new blank line at the end of the file. Why ? (Mine is a plain text file). Thanks again

Comment: @ThG Because `:redir` is bloated (it is not the only reason why you should avoid it where possible). `IndexByWord` is returning a NL-separated list of lines without empty ones, isn't it? Then you can use `call append('$', split(IndexByWord(...), "\n"))`. Better if you will add an extra argument to IndexByWord that will indicate whether function should return result_list itself or join it with newlines, in this case you won't need split(). Or just move `join(result_list, "\n")` outside of the function to the outer level where it is called.

Comment: @ZyX : Sorry for the late answer ; thanks to you and to Heikki Naski, the problem is solved. Unfortunately, I do not know how to credit you with an accepted answer... Thanks again